# How to find the Lower and Upper Byte from Hex value in PHP?

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.2, php-5.4

I have a series of Hex values like 0x1b12, 0x241B, 0x2E24, 0x392E and I need to calculate the Lower byte and Upper Byte from each of these hex values for further processing. How can I do that? I did a bit of research and saw that there is an **unpack** function in php but the "format" part in the argument is making me confused. Some of the unpack code that I've seen is added below.

```
unpack("C*",$data)
unpack("C*myint",$data)
unpack("c2chars/n2int",$data)
```

As mentioned the aforementioned code, I don't quite understand what "C*","C*myint","c2chars/n2int" does in the unpack function. So I'm not quite sure if I can use unpack as the solution to my problem. Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the pack function. It is easier and faster with [Bitwise Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

```
$val = 0x1b12;  //or $val = 6930;

$lowByte = $val & 0xff;  //int(18)
$uppByte = ($val >> 8) & 0xff;  //int(27)
```

The code needs an integer $val as input. If a string of the form "0x1b12" is available as input, then this must be converted into an integer:

```
$stringHex = "0x1b12";  //or "1b12"
$val = hexdec(ltrim($stringHex,'0x'));
```

ltrim is required so that no depreciation notice is generated from 7.4.0 onwards.

Comment: This. And if your hex number is a string, convert it to int first with `hexdec('0x1b12')`.

Comment: @jspit Many thanks for the answer. Would you be kind enough to tell me how this works actually?

Comment: The function of the bit operators is described in detail in the PHP manual. I linked the section.

Comment: @jspit Thanks for linking the manual. But I just wanted to understand the logic used in here.

Comment: The operation $val & 0xff filters the lowest 8 bits from the number. With $ val >> 8, the value of $val is shifted 8 bits to the right. 0x1b12 then becomes 0x1b. The repeated filtering is for safety.

Comment: @jspit However one problem that I ran into is, while converting a decimal value to a hexadecimal value using dechex this code doesn't seem to work correctly. It would be great if you could help me with this. Please see this pastebin. https://pastebin.com/5AetZRsz

Comment: I added to my answer. I hope it's more understandable now.